# Java launches CMD and multiple commands without builder

Tags: java, cmd, runtime.exec, bufferedwriter

I am wondering if there is way to make some kind of 'link' between java app and one window of CMD where I can post multiple commands separately -> without builder. Let's say next command have to be calculated, but pushed in the same CMD window.

In following example I tried to use BufferedWriter.write which does not work.
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Main.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        CmdProcess cmdProcess = new CmdProcess();

        cmdProcess.executeCmdCommand("echo Hello World");
        // I do not want to post commands together
        cmdProcess.executeCmdCommand("ping localhost");
    }
}
```

CmdProcess.java

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class CmdProcess {

    public CmdProcess() throws IOException {
        startUpProcess();
    }

    private Process cmd;
    private BufferedWriter writer;

    private void startUpProcess() throws IOException {
        String startCommand = "cmd.exe /c start ";
//        init CMD
        try {
            setCmd(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(startCommand));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
            throw new IOException("Not able to launch CMD in CmdProcess.startUpProcess().");
        }
//        init writer
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(getCmd().getOutputStream()));
    }

    public void executeCmdCommand(String command) throws IOException {
        writer.write(command);
        writer.flush();
    }

    public Process getCmd() {
        return cmd;
    }

    public void setCmd(Process cmd) {
        this.cmd = cmd;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String command) you can run multiple commands from a single command line or script using conditional operators.

```
command1 & command2 - Executes comand1 and then command2
command1 && command2 - 2nd command executes if 1st command exeutes successfully
```

Comment: You can refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-open-command-prompt-insert-commands/

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. This is really nice to know, anyway thing is I am searching for a way where I do not use a single command line or script, but way where I can send multiple commands separately. Is there any way? What do you think?

Comment: Why don't you use ProcessBuilder and pass the list of commands?

Comment: Let's say I need to post some commands and based on result send one or another. I want that logic on java side because I want e.g. use DB data. I do not want to prepare several scenario scripts for cmd.